# API Design when modifying resource data based on user roles (access levels)

Tags: api, api-design

I'm trying to figure out the best (and most RESTful) way to handle user roles in regards to the data returned.

For example, for a resource named `user`, we only show `obfuscated_id` to regular users and no `phone_number`. But for an admin, we return the regular `id` and also the user's `phone_number`.

What's the design for this. One option is to create `\admin\users` and `\users`. Which means I will need to have two routes for a single resource, which sounds a bit unRESTful

Comment: You really only want one resource.  There should be an access token sent in the request(typically in the header).  The server would then use the token to determine what to show.

Comment: @Cerad what about the cases when clients have a /admin/users (just for admins) and also /users (for everyone) I would need to return extra data when an admin is on the /users page then?

Comment: I'm afraid I can't help you out there.  REST typically has resources of which user might be one.  The notion of having an /admin/users resource makes little sense to me.  But that is just me.